# Gwyddion - high image resolution

Tags: image, resolution, dpi

I need to have the image after saving in Gwyddion in high resolution (at least 300dpi). By default it is saved in 72dpi. How can I get it? Can You help me?

Comment: Why do you need 300dpi? Are you trying to print it? What are the dimensions of your image in pixels - i.e. W pixels wide by H pixels tall?

Comment: I need such resolution for some papers. The dimension is different for each image but mostly about 650x500px.